# LARAVEL | input Data inside foreach of Table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have this form where i use foreach on table and i have to input value, is_active, target_id, period_id in the form. but when i click submit it does nothing

Services:

```
public function createOrUpdate(array $data, Period $period)
{
    foreach ($data['target_id'] as $index => $targetId) {
        $value = $data['value'][$index];
        $isActive = $data['is_active'][$index];

        // Check if the target period already exists
        $existingTarget = $period->targetPeriods()
            ->where('target_id', $targetId)
            ->exists();

        // Create or update the target period
        if ($existingTarget) {
            $period->targetPeriods()
                ->where('target_id', $targetId)
                ->update([
                    'value' => $value,
                    'is_active' => $isActive,
                ]);
        } else {
            $this->model->create([
                'target_id' => $targetId,
                'period_id' => $data['period_id'][$index],
                'value' => $value,
                'is_active' => $isActive,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

controller:

```
public function index(Period $period)
{
    $target = Target::get()->map(fn ($item) => [
        'id' => $item['id'],
        'name' => $item->parent_id ? $item->parent->name . ' | ' . $item['name'] : $item['name'],
    ]);

    $targetperiod = $period->targetPeriods->first();
    $periodId = $period->id;
    $period->load('program', 'challenge', 'targetPeriods');
    $routePeriod = route('admin.period.index');
    $routeStore = route('admin.period.targetperiod.store', ['period' => $period->id]);

    $targetPeriods = TargetPeriod::where('period_id', $periodId);
    $targets = Target::select('targets.*', 'target_periods.value')->leftJoinSub($targetPeriods, 'target_periods', function ($join) {
        $join->on('targets.id', '=', 'target_periods.target_id');
    })->get();

    return view('cms.target_period.index', compact('period', 'targets', 'periodId', 'routeStore', 'targetperiod', 'routePeriod'));
}

 public function store(Period $period, CreateTargetPeriodRequest $request)
{
    try {
        $this->targetPeriodService->createOrUpdate($request->validated(), $period);
        return redirect(route('admin.period.targetperiod.index', ['period' => $period->id]))->with('success', 'Target Period created');
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        return back()->withInput()->with('error', $th->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Form:

```
 <form action="{{ $routeStore }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <table id="" class="table table-bordered w-100">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>No</th>
                                <th>Target Name</th>
                                <th>Value</th>
                                <th>Is Active</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($targets as $index => $targetItem)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $index + 1 }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{ $targetItem['name'] }}
                                        <input type="text" name="target_id[]" class="form-control" value="{{ $targetItem['id'] }}" readonly>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="period_id[]" value="{{ $periodId }}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" name="value[]" id="value" placeholder="0" value="{{ isset($targetperiod) ? $targetperiod->value : old('value.'.$index, '0') }}">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="is_active[]" id="is_active" class="form-control" required>
                                            <option value="0" @selected(isset($targetperiod->is_active) ? $targetperiod->is_active == 0 : old('is_active'))>No</option>
                                            <option value="1" @selected(isset($targetperiod->is_active) ? $targetperiod->is_active == 1 : old('is_active'))>Yes</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

for now comment all of the request to see if the input goes through. when i click submitted, it return success but no data inside the tables. what goes wrong?

Comment: fyi, `id` attributes must be unique, yours aren't

Comment: @brombeer in which part?

Comment: All `id`s inside your loop will be repeated, so they're no longer unique (in the resulting HTML). Most likely not the cause of your problem though. Did you check the request in your browser's DevTools?

Comment: yes it returns nothing, there is no error whatsoever, and i just dd in my services. it return an empty array

Comment: What exactly do you `dd()` and when/where? None of your method has a `Request $request` parameter

Comment: i edited it, i forgot to put the store controller in the question, i dd($data) inside my services on function createOrUpdate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256727/discussion-between-dava-eranda-and-brombeer).